# Dynamically reload multer with new limits fileSize value

Tags: node.js, express, dynamic, multer

I'm using these lines to initialize multer:

```
file_size_limit=1000000;
var multer  = require('multer');
upload = multer({ dest: 'upload/', limits: { fileSize: global.file_size_limit }}).array('fileUploaded');
```

And in the route i use for example:

```
router.post('/', global.upload, function(req, res, next) {
```

What i have already achieved with busboy is that, i can create an admin section, and change the file size limit, which restricts the size of uploaded files. There is no need to restart the server as the `var busboy = ...` functionality lies within the `router.post('/', function(req, res, next){})` ..
I am not able to do this in multer without restarting the server.

Is it possible to re-assign `upload` variable with new multer settings on a given route being accessed?

Could be something like this...

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next){
  global.upload = multer({ dest: 'upload/', limits: { fileSize: new_file_size_limit }}).array('fileUploaded');
});
```

Right now all i can think of is to save the new setting of `fileSize` in a database and then write a .js file which would make the server restart using nodemon (which monitors code changes and restarts if any)...

Can this be done without restarting the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, i found how to do this. For others facing this problem, i'm posting the solution here. The upload variable can be nested inside the req, res of the route. (It is not necessary that upload variable is a parameter in the route itself)

The code would look like this:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var upload = multer({ dest: 'upload/', limits: { fileSize: req.app.locals.size }}).array('myfile');
  upload(req, res,function(err) {
          if(err) {
              return res.end(err.toString());
          }
          console.log(req.body);
          var tmp_path = req.files[0].path;
          var target_path = '/home/' + req.files[0].originalname;
          fs.rename(tmp_path, target_path, function(err) {
                 if (err) throw err;
          });
          res.redirect('back');
      });
});
```